# App is not successfully being uploaded

Tags: ios, upload, app-store

I am trying to deploy my app on app store after removing the leading white space in the product name, but this time i am facing the following errors.

1) Apple's web service was not successful.
2) Unable to authenticate the package 
3)Your package contains a file 'AR Reader .app/AR Reader ' with a name that contains leading or trailing whitespace characters.
Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then deliver the corrected binary.

I have tried too many solutions from stack overflow but still not able to solve the problem

But i have removed the space, please guide me as i am new to iOS